# How do I add and remove HTML elements with only HTML5 and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a drop down navigation menu when people use my website on mobile devices but I only know HTML and CSS. How can I add HTML to my HTML file when my website is being used on mobile devices?

Comment: Actually adding/removing elements from the DOM is not achievable with only HTML and CSS. You need Javascript for that.

Comment: You can make the menu hidden by default and only made visible when a css media query determines that the device is probably mobile.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok ill start learning JavaScript soon

Comment: @aptriangle thank you so much for the info! i will do that!

Comment: @mplungjan i looked for help from google for 30 min i couldnt find anything im sorry i guess ill look for more time next time

Comment: I just googled your question. "css show navigation mobile only"